# Erlang Printing N times

Tags: recursion, erlang

I am trying to teach myself some erlang and I keep getting an error that i do not understand.

I am trying to make a function that takes an integer N and prints "Hello World" N times, so that i can then hotswap the message (havent gotten to that part yet).

My code:

```
-module(repeater).
-export([repeat/1], [start/0]).

repeat(Num) when is_Integer(Num), Num > 0 ->

    if Num == 1 ->
        io:fwrite("Hello World"),
        io:fwrite("~n");

     else ->
        io:fwrite(pass(Num - 1));

     true ->
        io:fwrite("I have no idea what is happening")

     end.

start() ->
    repeat(3).
```

The error message i get is:

```
 repeater.erl:7: bad export declaration 
 repeater.erl:11: Warning: function pass/1 is unused
 repeater.erl:21: Warning: function start/0 is unused
```

I dont know why it says it is "Unused".

I find this language challenging to pick up for myself seeing as i cant even get an if else block working correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing
`-export([repeat/1], [start/0]).`
with
`-export([repeat/1, start/0]).`

regarding the guard expression, you got a typo in `is_Integer()`, should be `is_integer()`

regarding your `if` condition,
there's no point of using `else -> io:fwrite(pass(Num-1))`. any atom except `true` evaluates to `false` so any atom except `true` is useless here. `if` needs to have at least one clause evaluating to `true` and since you already have a catch-all clause `true -> io:fwrite("I have no idea what is happening")` which is going to be called in case if `Num` is larger than 1, you don't need any other clauses

Comment: That stopped those errors!, but now the code evaluates to the true case which if i am passing 3 as a parameter i feel like that should not be happening?

Comment: could you add the definition of "pass( )" to your post?

Comment: Sorry, pass is supposed to be repeat(), i changed the name because i didnt like pass as a function name for the purposes of this post/ in general after thinking about it

Comment: Also, I am getting "illegal guard expression", is it the Num is > 0 you think or is_Integer(Num)?

Comment: @Geedubs123, is_Integer is not valid. See [the docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_integer-1)